# How can I check my progress towards a particular badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, profile-page

Specifical, I want to know about the Struck & White badge. I seem to remember at one point that the number of edits to posts that I have made appeared somewhere on the page, but it doesn't seem to be visible at the moment (not displayed on mobile perhaps?)

Review tasks shows a bar and a hashmark.

Generalist you can check by examining your tags.

Deputy (helpful) flags are displayed just below you logins.

Fanatic (consecutive days) are displayed on your profile.

Are there any tags that don't display your progress?

It might be best to have a complete listing of how to find out your progress for each badge.

Comment: Research Assistant (editing tag wikis) seems particularly difficult to find. Best I've been doing is counting the +2 rep I get for tag wiki edits, but those will go away when I become a Trusted User.

Comment: @shujaa Actually, it's not that difficult. All you have to do is go to *info* tab subpage of any tag - example of [mtg tag info](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/magic-the-gathering/info). On the very right you can find something like this: `Your Badge Progress` (Research Assistant) `2 tag wiki edits (4% done)`. Cheers. Does anyone have a way of finding out progress towards Sportmanship badge?

Answer (score 4):

Progress towards Strunk & White [used to be displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112401/badge-progress-indicator-in-review-section) in the [review tab](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review), replaced with progress towards Copy Editor once you achieved it. That doesn't seem to be the case any more, which is probably a [regression bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152529/why-is-the-strunk-and-white-badge-not-shown-in-the-review-badge-progress-mouseov).

If you hover over the gray progress bar for any of the review queues, you can see progress towards several badges (Custodian/Reviewer, Civic Duty, Copy Editor and Electorate).

In general, there is no single place to track badge progress. I also find this quite annoying. For a long time, it was policy [not to provide any badge progress indicators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports) at all.

Which badges are tracked, and where their progress can be seen, has changed somewhat over time, so searching historical questions for links on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) is not hugely rewarding. You may like to raise a feature request over there for a centralised badge tracking, or ask for a complete current list.

Comment: Notably, one *can* track one's badge progress through the data querier interface mathing, but that dataset lags. When I've approved edits, I still get the progress tracker bar, though.